# Blurring JPG image using Java

Tags: java, image-processing

I have an .jpg image that is generated by an application. What I want to do with it is, using java, blur out a box on the .jpg to a point where any text or content would not be able to be read, but doesn't aesthetically ruin the picture.

How would I go about doing this?

Edit:
I guess I'm needing more direction than just a simple how to do this. I don't have any background in image processing. What kind of java libraries or tools should I be looking at using?

Comment: i think you r talking about opacity

Comment: Set a rectangle inside the image, like a crop window.  Blacken or whiten the rectangle.

Comment: Check out the sample here  https://github.com/madhur/blur-java